# Как использовать Protocol Buffer без файлов

Tags: java, google-protobuf

Есть примеры где наглядно показывается как мне сохранить данные в файл и считать их, не могу понять как мне эти данные просто передать к примеру просто закрепив в посте, или просто передать этот класс в другой метод.

```
AddressBook.Builder addressBook = AddressBook.newBuilder();

// Read the existing address book.
try {
  addressBook.mergeFrom(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println(args[0] + ": File not found.  Creating a new file.");
}

// Add an address.
addressBook.addPerson(
  PromptForAddress(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)),
                   System.out));

// Write the new address book back to disk.
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(args[0]);
addressBook.build().writeTo(output);
output.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте не `FileInputStream/FileOutputStream`, а другие уместные в вашем случае потоки ввода/вывода. Например это могут быть `ByteArrayInputStream` и `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
// пишем
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
addressBook.build().writeTo(baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

// читаем
AddressBook addressBook = AddressBook.parseFrom(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
```

Или, например, `OutputStream` HTTP-соединения:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://...").openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");         
addressBook.build().writeTo(conn.getOutputStream());
```

---

Впрочем, для работы именно с байт-массивом [документация предлагает](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#parsing-and-serialization) готовые методы:

> `byte[] toByteArray();`: сериализует сообщение и возвращает массив байтов.
>
> `static Person parseFrom(byte[] data);`: парсит сообщение из массива байтов.

То есть что-то вроде:

```
// пишем
byte[] data = addressBook.toByteArray();

// читаем
addressBook = AddressBook.parseFrom(data);
```